# How can I set the hostPath volume permission on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

It seems by default Kubernetes creates a hostPath volume with `755` permission on a directory.

Is it possible to set this value to something else by a `volume` spec? As opposed to manually doing a `chmod` on the relevent host directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  initContainers:
    - name: volume-mount-hack
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh", "-c", "chmod -R 777 /tmp/docker"]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: redis-socket
        mountPath: /tmp/docker
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get "chmod: /tmp/docker: Operation not permitted"