# Changing ownership /data/db, input/output error, Kubernetes Mongo Deployment

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run a deployment for mongo using minikube. I have created a persistent storage using the following configuration:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: mongo-claim
  hostPath:
    path: "/test"
```

The `"/test"` folder is being mounted using `minikube mount <local_path>:/test`

Then I created a PV Claim using the following configuration:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
```

Finally, I am trying to create a Service and Deployment with the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: backend
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: "mongo"
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: mongo-config
        ports:
          - name: mongo-port
            containerPort: 27017 
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mongo-storage
            mountPath: "/data/db"
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mongo-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: mongo-port
```

The container quits with an error Changing ownership of '/data/db', Input/Output error.

Question 1) Who is trying to change the ownership of the internal directory of the container? Is it the PV Claim?
Question 2) Why the above culprit is trying to mess with the permission of the Mongodb container's default storage path?

Comment: You need to add an init container to set the rights before placing the database on it, or change your db user in the pod to root.

Comment: I get that point, as the error is pretty straight forward but isn’t that the best part of k8s that it handles shit on its own? which level is entering the problematic situation is it the issue with minikube mounts?

Comment: Databases tend to be ran with a specific user, and in theory you could even use different users within one container. At this point in time there is (except just giving blanket do everything rights) no way to let a system figure this out, so it is the traditional having to manage the rights yourself.

Comment: can you just resolve this particular issue who is trying to change the permissions for /data/db inside the container?

Comment: [Arpit Goyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4719293/arpit-goyal) there is few ways for resolve your issue they already described on stack:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769339/how-to-change-permission-of-mapped-volume-in-kubernetes-docker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765379/how-can-i-set-the-hostpath-volume-permission-on-kubernetes)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it more about virtualbox driver for external folder then k8s itself,

in my scenario

- i've created a folder on my OS X,
- mapped that folder to minikube `minikube mount data-storage/:/data-storage`
- created PersistentVolume pointing to folder inside minikube
- created PersistentVolumeClaim pointing to PV above
- tried to start single simple mongodb using PVC above

and got constantly restarting pods with logs:

`Fatal Assertion` and `fsync: Invalid Argument`
was fighting for a few hours, and finally found this

https://github.com/mvertes/docker-alpine-mongo/issues/1

which is basically reporting issues with virtualbox driver in case if folder mapped to host.

Once i've mapped PersistentVolume to `/data` inside of minikube - my pod went live like a charm.

i my case i've decided since minikube is development environment there no reason to be stuck on this

**UPDATE:**

i wish i would found out this earlier, would save me some time!

**docker CE desktop has built in kubernetes!**

all you need is to go to the properties and turn it on, that's it no need in virtual box or minikube at all.

and the best thing is that shared folders (on File Sharing tab) - are available for kubernetes - checked with mongodb inside of k8s. 
And it way faster then minikube (which was failing all the time by the way on my OS X).

Hope it's going to save someone time.